# how to update and read JSON file from azure function and azure runbook in powershell?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I'm looking to read and update JSON file from the Azure file storage using node js written in azure function and power shell notebook from azure automation.
How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend clarifying your question, as it is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to use Azure Functions or Azure Automation? PowerShell or Node.js? What have you tried? What didn't work?

Comment: I'm using both of them, but at first priority, I have to read and update the JSON file from the azure functions

Answer (score 1):

For now the Azure Function doesn't support the Azure File Storage binding, so if you want to read file in function, you have to use the storage ndoejs SDK. You could refer to my code, I use this [SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node) to test.

```
    var azure = require('azure-storage');
    var fileService = azure.createFileService(process.env["AzureWebJobsStorage"]);
    var fs = require('fs');
    var shareName='windows';
    var dirPath='';
    var fileName='test.json'
    //read the json data
    fileService.getFileToText(shareName, dirPath, fileName, function(error, result, response) {
        console.log(result);
    });

    var json='{"george":"test"}';
    //update the json file
    fileService.createFileFromText(shareName, dirPath, fileName, json,function(error, result, response) {
        console.log(result);
        fileService.getFileToText(shareName, dirPath, fileName, function(error, result, response) {
            console.log(result);
        });
    });
```

And here is the result picture.

[image]

Comment: hi, thank you for the response can I do the same with Azure blob, storage.

Comment: @saran k, of course you could do same thing to blob. Here is the sample about [blob storage](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node#blob-storage).However there is blob binding, with bind it's easier to implement it. You could refer to this [input binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#input---javascript-example) and [output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#output---javascript-example).

Comment: @saran k, and if this could help you, please accept it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I'm also looking to do it from power shell code in runbook

Comment: @saran k, I suppose this is easy to get it.  There is [getfilecontent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/get-azurestoragefilecontent?view=azurermps-6.13.0) and [getblobcontent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/get-azurestorageblobcontent?view=azurermps-6.13.0) moethod.

Comment: @saran k, any process now? If you still have problem, please feel free to let me know.